# I am getting this warning Warning: Error loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am upgrading from rails 2.3 to rails 3.2. I have models divided into sub folders. Just like there is a model app/models/ad/ad.rb the other app/models/ad/ad_city.rb but inside the model it is written as:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
class AdCity < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and not:

```
class Ad::Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
class Ad::AdCity < ActiveRecord::Base
```

I have in my application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

even I tried including each folder in config.autoload_paths. But it give me a thousand lines warning:

```
Warning: Error loading /home/deep/projects/upgrade/models/myapp/app/models/ad/ad_city.rb:
uninitialized constant Ad::AdCity
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.11/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in load_models'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.11/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:54:in `each'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.11/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:54:in `block in load_models'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.11/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:53:in `each'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.11/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:53:in `load_models'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.11/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:15:in `prepare'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.11/lib/thinking_sphinx.rb:81:in `block in context'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.11/lib/thinking_sphinx.rb:78:in `synchronize'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.11/lib/thinking_sphinx.rb:78:in `context'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.11/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record.rb:162:in `define_index'
/home/deep/projects/upgrade/models/myapp/app/models/user/user_indexes.rb:6:in `included'
/home/deep/projects/upgrade/models/myapp/app/models/user/user.rb:295:in `include'
/home/deep/projects/upgrade/models/myapp/app/models/user/user.rb:295:in `<class:User>'
/home/deep/projects/upgrade/models/myapp/app/models/user/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/bundler/gems/rails-dev-boost-bf49caca6670/lib/rails_development_boost/dependencies_patch.rb:364:in `block in load_file_with_constant_tracking_internal'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/bundler/gems/rails-dev-boost-bf49caca6670/lib/rails_development_boost/dependencies_patch.rb:240:in `now_loading'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/bundler/gems/rails-dev-boost-bf49caca6670/lib/rails_development_boost/dependencies_patch.rb:364:in `load_file_with_constant_tracking_internal'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/bundler/gems/rails-dev-boost-bf49caca6670/lib/rails_development_boost/dependencies_patch.rb:234:in `block in load_file_with_constant_tracking'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/bundler/gems/rails-dev-boost-bf49caca6670/lib/rails_development_boost/dependencies_patch.rb:383:in `async_synchronize'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/bundler/gems/rails-dev-boost-bf49caca6670/lib/rails_development_boost/dependencies_patch.rb:229:in `load_file_with_constant_tracking'
/home/deep/projects/upgrade/models/myapp/lib/authenticated_system.rb:108:in `login_from_session'
/home/deep/projects/upgrade/models/myapp/lib/authenticated_system.rb:24:in `current_user'
/home/deep/projects/upgrade/models/myapp/lib/authenticated_system.rb:14:in `logged_in?'
/home/deep/projects/upgrade/models/myapp/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:288:in `set_timezone'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__402496120916004207__process_action__1098406492416702350__callbacks'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notification/rack.rb:28:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/bundler/gems/rails-dev-boost-bf49caca6670/lib/rails_development_boost/async.rb:14:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2960753221531180313__call__4371824738127159201__callbacks'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/better_errors-2.0.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/better_errors-2.0.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/better_errors-2.0.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade_mygemset/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/deep/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/deep/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/deep/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

for all the models. It doesn't throw any error just gives warning each time my app makes any connection with the database. What should I do. Please help

Comment: What happens if you don't include config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')] ?

Comment: It doesn't include any model in the application. It throws an error.